# Cant Run this Python File. Can you help?

Tags: kali-linux, python

I am using Kali Linux 2019 ,
Trying to install this Source :

I am not using apt-get install , i am installing manual , but i got a question , can i do apt-get install as showen here in https://pastebin.com/SfQMJwFf , and skip download the package of gnuradio only , Because gnuradio i got it installed manual , but i need the other files examples gnuradio-dev , gr-osmosdr , becuase i dont need to install last version of gnuradio which is 3.8 i need to install 3.7 , so because of that i did install it manual , same as gr-osmosdr which is my error –

https://github.com/ptrkrysik/multi-rtl

I have installed everything required,
but what dose this, here, mean here?

I run `./mutlirtl_rx_to_cfile_2chan.py` as root, and get this error message.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./mutlirtl_rx_to_cfile_2chan.py", line 17, in <module>
    import multi_rtl
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/multi_rtl/__init__.py", line 30, in <module>
    from multi_rtl_source import multi_rtl_source
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/multi_rtl/multi_rtl_source.py", line 27, in <module>
    import osmosdr
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/osmosdr/__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    from osmosdr_swig import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/osmosdr/osmosdr_swig.py", line 13, in <module>
    from . import _osmosdr_swig
ImportError: /usr/local/lib/libgnuradio-osmosdr-0.1.5.so.0.0.0: undefined symbol: _ZN5boost6chrono12steady_clock3nowEv
```

Any help how to fix it?

Comment: Looks like you're missing a library. Please [edit] your question to tell us what you're installing, what instructions you followed, and on what system (Linux distribution or UNIX type)

Comment: Done , i have edit  , i am using linux ,

Comment: You're using Kali Linux. It's not a general purpose distribution and you will find strange corners. This may be one. Did you get any errors at all when you followed the build/installation instructions?

Comment: No i didnt get any errors when build and install

Comment: That's good. What about for the `apt-get install ...` line - did it find all the packages?

Comment: I am not using apt-get install , i am installing manual

Comment: I am not using apt-get install , i am installing manual , but i got a question , can i do apt-get install as showen here in pastebin https://pastebin.com/SfQMJwFf , and skip download the package of gnuradio only , cuz gnuradio i got it installed manual , but i need the other files examples gnuradio-dev , gr-osmosdr , becuase i dont need to install last version of gnuradio which is 3.8 i need to install 3.7 , so because of that i did install it manual , same as gr-osmosdr which is my error

Comment: stop banging your head against a wall ... get rid of Kali, it is not for your knowledge level ... get a user friendly linux distribution such as Ubuntu or Mint

Answer (score 2):

It appears from a [comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/602413/cant-run-this-python-file-can-you-help#comment1123909_602413) that you have not followed the [installation instructions](https://github.com/ptrkrysik/multi-rtl) to install a set of prebuilt supporting packages.

If you haven't installed the packages as described in the installation instructions, the application can't work.

Comment: Why i cant install Python-Scipy ?

Answer (score 1):

> ImportError: /usr/local/lib/libgnuradio-osmosdr-0.1.5.so.0.0.0: undefined symbol: _ZN5boost6chrono12steady_clock3nowEv

This is a C/CPP error from an external library used in your python program and not a bug in the python program itself. This can happen when a depending library was updated but the one throwing the error was not.

The particular lib was linked against other libraries. You can find which one in particular with the command `ldd /usr/local/lib/libgnuradio-osmosdr-0.1.5.so.0.0.0`

If this yields a missing library you have to reinstall/provide the missing library.

If none is missing you may need to *recompile* whatever provided `libgnuradio-osmosdr`.

It's hard to tell because it's in `/usr/local` and we can't know how it ended up there (read: not installed by the packet manager of your system).

It may help to uninstall it by whatever script you installed it there and reinstall it. This will probably trigger a rebuild of some sort and fix this error.

Comment: This is what i get when i do ldd /usr/local/lib/libgnuradio-osmosdr-0.1.5.so.0.0.0  https://pastebin.com/4awFUR1m  i have tried to reinstall still same error !

Comment: Did it recompile before you `installed` it? Please send the manual you followed.

Comment: i just install gnuradio manual from this link https://wiki.gnuradio.org/index.php/InstallingGR

Comment: I give up. This page holds installing instructions for various distributions _and_ operating systems. The word "manual" does not even show up on that page. How is anyone supposed to help if you do not manage to provide sufficient information? Also I fail to see the connection to the _osmosdr_ lib at all that seems to be part of `gr-osmosdr`. I also found https://wiki.gnuradio.org/index.php/FAQ#In_my_OOT_Module.2C_I.27m_trying_to_use_a_GNU_Radio_block_or_class_but_get_an_ImportError_.22undefined_symbol.22._What_do_I_do.3F on that Wiki.

Comment: I got problem , which is when i install the Gnuradio manual , its installed 100% , but when i try to do apt-get install gnuradio its also give me to install it again with version 3.8 , and i already installed in manual gnuradio 3.7 , what is going on here

Comment: When i just Cmake .. in file gr-osmosdr its give me this error but its build it 100% here the error at this link : pastebin.com/T5aNpaSa –

Comment: I _assume_ you installed some libraries in `/lib` this time but the lib is shadowed by _the same_ lib under `/usr/local/lib`. Clean up your system and make sure that only the "good" libraries are installed. You seem to have multiple libraries with the same name installed and your script loads the "bad" one.